# Mailgun and Laravel returning T_Double_Arrow error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sendmail, mailgun

I am trying to get Mailgun to work as my email provider.

By adding the `services.php` page into `app/config` and filling in the credentials, I'm left with this:

```
<?php
'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => 'domain.com',
    'secret' => 'key-removedforprivacy',
),
```

When I go to execute a `Mail::` function, it returns this error:

`syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

It relates to this line:

`'mailgun' => array(`

If I remove `<?php`, it actually gets past this step, but returns the error where it can't find the array with the `domain` and `secret` values.

I've copied the code from Laravel's website! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is not valid PHP (The interpreter is correct.  It's *always* correct.)

I think this is what you're trying to do

```
<?php
return array(
    'mailgun' => array(
        'domain' => 'domain.com',
        'secret' => 'key-removedforprivacy',
    ),
);
```